# Unable to resolve com.aspose.pdf

Tags: java, maven, pdf, aspose, aspose.pdf

I try to use `Aspose` solutions to handle `PDF` documents, but unable to resolve these classes:

```
import com.aspose.pdf.Document;
import com.aspose.pdf.FileSpecification;
```

I already imported `aspose-pdf-2.9.0-jdk16.jar` into project and added following code to `pom.xml` file, but nothing changed.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aspose</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspose-pdf</artifactId>
        <version>11.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.media.jai</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.springsource.javax.media.jai.core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>aspose-maven-repository</id>
        <url>http://maven.aspose.com/repository/repo/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.external</id>
        <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - External Bundle Releases</name>
        <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Akos,

The reason you are getting an error is because you are using an older version of API and com.aspose.pdf.Document class became available in release versions starting 6.0.0. Please get the latest release version of [Aspose.Pdf for Java 17.7](https://downloads.aspose.com/pdf/java/new-releases/aspose.pdf-for-java-17.7/) and see if it resolves the problem.

PS, my name is Nayyer and I am developer evangelist at Aspose.

Answer (score 1):

@Akos,

Our repository URL has changed. Please use following repository info. Thanks.

```
<repository>
  <id>aspose-maven-repository</id>
  <url>https://repository.aspose.com/repo/</url>
</repository>
```